# How to integrate Speech to Text with QnA Maker Based Bot?

Tags: botframework, speech-to-text, azure-qna-maker

I have developed a FAQ Bot using C# and Bot Builder SDK 3.15.3. We have a large set of question/answer pairs which are uploaded to a QNA Maker Service. I have enabled the Direct Line Channel and the bot is displayed on a web page. I have used the Web Chat control provided by Microsoft with some customization and skinning.

Now I want to enable voice interaction with the bot, for that I decided to use the Microsoft Speech to Text Cognitive Service.

What I want to do is that when ever user speaks some utterance, I want to send the utterance to my bot service similar to like text is sent. Then inside C# code I want to run the Speech to Text and further do a Spell Check on the text retrieved and finally send to QNA Maker Service. The response for now will only be showed as text, but can also opt to read the response for the user.

Kindly guide my how this is achievable, as after looking at CognitiveService.js and other articles on enabling speech, I notice that Web Chat control directly sends the voice input to speech to text service.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a hybrid between a calling bot which utilizes speech to text and a QnA bot to achieve your goal. For the calling bot, look over the [SimpleIVRbot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-V3/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/SimpleIVRBot/SimpleIVRBot.cs) sample to get you going. For QnAMaker, you can reference the [SimpleQnABot](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-CognitiveServices/tree/master/CSharp/Samples/QnAMaker/SimpleQnABot). It shouldn't take *too* much work bridging the two into a single unified bot. Just be sure to remove duplicate code and combine files where necessary.

Hope of help!